# Keyboard Shortcut for react.js application using material UI?

Tags: reactjs, web, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to implement a keyboard shortcut in react.js project i am using material UI components.

The default keys which browser supports are tab, shift, enter and arrow keys.

I want to implement function keys to navigate into specific area of my web application.

Comment: Hi Fahad. What exactly is your question? Would you like some guidance on how to design keyboard shortcuts, or on how to implement a shortcut that will set focus to an element on the page? Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you are using the right HTML elements for your areas, like `<main>` or `<region>` or `<footer>`, and that they carry an accessible name by means of `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`. The ARIA role for an area on a page is landmark:

> A landmark is an abstract role for a section of content that is important enough that users will likely want to be able to navigate to the section easily and have it included in a dynamically generated summary of the page. Landmarks allow assistive technologies to navigate and to find content quickly.

[ARIA: landmark role on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/landmark_role)

#### Use Skip Links

Then, you might consider using [Skip Links](https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/) that allow keyboard users to navigate to these landmarks directly by means of <kbd>tab</kbd>. This might also give you an opportunity to communicate the Shortcuts you are providing.

#### Shortcuts

When providing shortcuts, it’s important to not use shortcuts that are already in use on the user’s platform. These should still work as expected.

Also, if you are using single character shortcuts, you need to provide a mechanism to change these shortcuts, should they interfere with other AT shortcuts:

[Understanding Success Criterion 2.1.4: Character Key Shortcuts](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/character-key-shortcuts.html)

One way to implement shortcuts is the native `accesskey` attribute, but browser and AT support is not great.

[Accesskey on WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey#concept)

Usually, these keys are used for interactive elements, not for landmarks. So if you want to focus a landmark, you will need to make it focusable first:

```html
<main id="main" tabindex="-1">
```

Then you can bind on the [keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) and focus the corresponding landmark in turn.

```js
document.documentElement.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  switch(e.key) {
    case "F1":
      document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].focus();
      break;
  }
})
```

As this only works on the DOM, you will need to bind this handler either to your root instead of the documentElement, or where you render your application.

#### Web Applications and <kbd>tab</kbd>

If you implemented arrow key navigation for components in your application, it might be pretty fast for users to reach a landmark/component by means of <kbd>tab</kbd>, and implementing skip links or shortcuts might be less interesting.